# Are ecosystem questions in scope?

Tags: discussion

I have trouble with this question: [How to push a GitHub repo to the wordpress plugin servers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/how-to-push-a-github-repo-to-the-wordpress-plugin-servers)

There is nothing about that but Git and Subversion, neither of which are specific to WordPress. However as a task to get done and as a workflow practice this is something many WP developers would probably find interesting.

Do we want it here for practical value? Or do we get rid of it as unspecific?

Comment: My vote is to keep it here. I would love to hear some thoughts in this topic.

Comment: I have no right answer. :) I share your conundrum, as the question clearly isn't in the WPSE scope, but at the same time, the discussion - and answer - would be interesting and beneficial to many developers.

Answer (score 2):

just wanted to chime in.

While it is true that it is not technically specific to Wordpress, and that Wordpress could be taken out of the question and it would still be complete, i think that misses the point.

The primary reason I've come to frequent stackexchange is because I find the answers useful. The average user is less concerned with the specifics of whether a question fits better on one domain of stackexchange or another, than whether they find what they are looking for, and what they find is useful.

This question is a good example of that. I'm just learning version control and would have had no idea that pushing Github to SVN is the same independent of Wordpress. Reading the questions AND answers (and this) helped me realize that. Thus, I think rather than taking a question that is - arguably - worthy of being closed / moved - might it be better to simply answer the question in a more wordpress specific manner?

> Pushing from GitHub to SVN is a well documented process independent
>   of it being tied to wordpress. See xxxx answer. Many people find it
>   useful to host on both as seen in zzzz answer.

While it would lead to some redundancy across the site's, a person like me searching "Github Wordpress SVN" might be more likely to find this very useful question.

Again, if its somehow detrimental to the system, then please dis-regard this. But overall, I see a fair amount of useless / terribles Questions floating about - while this one may be redundant, I find it very useful.

Comment: Thanks for adding your opinion! Note that process of scope definition is largely community-guided. Since this is too large for my personal moderator decision I brought it up for community discussion and (if necessary) scope will be bent to fit community decision, not the other way. So don't treat your opinion as disposable - it is important and will be absolutely taken in account (well - as far as my powers go at least :)

Answer (score 1):

Would we allow questions about code editors, unless they were related to WordPress in some way?

Some examples:

> "What NetBeans extensions do you use for WordPress development?"

Good question, because it relates to WP workflow.

> "Can I auto-indent WordPress code in NetBeans?"

That's a not-so-good question, since there's no such thing as "WordPress code". There's only PHP, JavaScript or CSS.

So, in my opinion, these sorts of questions should be closed, but not deleted. Ideally, they should have a link to a good resource on the general topic.

Comment: Good examples. +1 I hope you don't mind the edit.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, "WordPress" could also have stayed as [tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) on SO. But it isn't.

So Qs like the following are *IMHO* valid:

**PHP**

> "How can I get the meta data key X from the $post object?"

**CSS**

> "How can I style the current menu item?"

**JavaScript**

> "How can I remove the jQuery definitions that allow to drag meta boxes?"

**SVN/Git**

> ["How-to: push a GitHub repo to the wordpress plugin servers"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/how-to-push-a-github-repo-to-the-wordpress-plugin-servers)

---

If you'd, like from @scribu suggested, close them, you'd also close the door for later improvements of the As or even better As.

Comment: From your examples SVN/GIt is the only one that **doesn't change at all when you remove WP from it**. There is simply no difference between WP official Subversion repository and random Subversion repository on the Internet. That's why I think this specific question is especially tricky.

Comment: Just for purposes of discussion: perhaps we may want to consider *revising* our scope, to account for some of these scenarios? Note: I have no particular opinion on the matter; rather, I merely advocate that we have a *defined* scope, and that we *adhere* to it. If the community believes that our defined scope needs to be expanded, let's expand it.

Comment: Agree with @ChipBennet Scope shouldn't be engraved.

Comment: I will say that, for your given examples: I agree that most are *already* in-scope, but the answers should still be limited to the parts of the question that *are* in-scope. It is one thing to discuss the CSS classes generated by WordPress (which is clearly *in* scope); it is another thing entirely to discuss *CSS styling* (which is *out* of scope).